# Fan speed control softkey is inactive on Lenovo z480 running Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, lenovo-laptop

Although it is stated in the manual that the fan speed control softkey would give us four different options to choose from, my Z480 Ideapad Lenovo on Win8 has a different scenario. Once this softkey is pressed, ONLY the dust cleaning is performed. There is no other option to choose from. I am wondering whether this is an issue with Win8 on this model of notebook or it is about the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Features like that often require a software component, in your case that's [Lenovo Energy Management for Microsoft Windows 8 (32-bit, 64-bit) - Notebook](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS031269). Is that piece of software installed?